# Delete a child record from a specific parent record

Tags: mongodb

I am pretty new to mongodb.  I have 3 levels of documents.

Parent > Child > Child, all having _id field.

```
{
    "_id" : "n2qw5sojs4bajrj",
    "Title" : "Mr",
    "Instance" : "HQ",
    "FirstName" : "ppp",
    "LastName" : "uuuu",
    "Position" : "BF",
    "EmailAddress" : "xxx@ppp.com",
    "Requests" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "121",
            "Date" : "12/02/2018",
            "Status" : "New",
            "ApprovedBy" : {
                "_id" : "sdfsdf",
                "Name" : "MAN"
            },
            "PPE" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "121",
                    "Code" : "PPE",
                    "Status" : "New",
                    "Title" : "Trousers",
                    "Type" : "STD",
                    "Size" : "10111116",
                    "Qty" : 1,
                    "LostDamage" : {
                        "Reason" : "asdaD",
                        "Location" : "Station",
                        "Damage" : "Damged"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "122",
                    "Code" : "PPEOPP",
                    "Status" : "New",
                    "Title" : "TrousASDASDASDers",
                    "Type" : "STD",
                    "Size" : "10111116",
                    "Qty" : 1,
                    "LostDamage" : {
                        "Reason" : "asdaD",
                        "Location" : "Station",
                        "Damage" : "Damged"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like find out how to delete the last PPE Element (Parent > Request > PPE) by the _id column.

So I would to delete the following child:

```
{
                        "_id" : "121",
                        "Code" : "PPE",
                        "Status" : "New",
                        "Title" : "Trousers",
                        "Type" : "STD",
                        "Size" : "10111116",
                        "Qty" : 1,
                        "LostDamage" : {
                            "Reason" : "asdaD",
                            "Location" : "Station",
                            "Damage" : "Damged"
                        }
                    }
```

Any tips / help would be great.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDb $pop to remove your last element from array. Like this go to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/

```
 db.collection.update({id:1}, { $pop:{ 'request.PPE':1}});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to find a PPE with ID of 121. I have tried the following "db.getCollection('Member').update({_id:'n2qw5sojs4bajrj', "Requests._id":"121"},{ '$pull': { 
    'PPE._id':'121'}})", it says it has updated but the record is still present.

Comment: You forgot to mention your parent property i.e 'Requests.PPE' so your query should be.    "db.getCollection('Member').update({_id:'n2qw5sojs4bajrj', "Requests._id":"121"},{ '$pull': { 'Requests.PPE': {_id:{$e: 121}}}})",

Comment: Hi @Nasir, thank you,  I had to change the query to this: db.getCollection('Member').update({_id:'n2qw5sojs4bajrj', "Requests._id":"121"},{ '$pull': { 'Requests.PPE': {_id:{$eq: 121}}}}) but getting the following error: "Cannot use the part (PPE) of (Requests.PPE).... Did not like $e, change to $eq.

Comment: This is what it should be, "db.getCollection('Member').update({ "_id": "n2qw5sojs4bajrj", "Requests._id": "121", "Requests.PPE._id": "122" },{$pull : {"Requests.$.PPE":{ _id:"121"}}})"

Comment: This is final solution that i have tested in my system

db.getCollection('Member').update({_id:'n2qw5sojs4bajrj', "Requests._id":"121"},{ '$pull': { 'Requests.$.PPE': {_id:'121'}}})